# In Rails, how to handle asynchronous requests that requires severall calls to facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

In my `Rails` app, I use the `Koala` gem to handle my requests to Facebook.
I would like to make those requests asynchronously without preventing my server to handle new requests.

So, I need to have:

1. asynchronous controller
2. asynchronous requests to Facebook

What is the best way to achieve that?